# How to open an external html page as a popup in jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a link like this

```
<a href='/path/to/popup.html' data-role="button">COME HERE </a>
```

I want to open the `popup.html file as a jquery popup.` And I cant have it inside the current page as a `<div>` with an id. I must have it out side the current file.

And `I cant use dialog's as it reloads the current page.` Any idea on how to do it?

Inside the `popup.html I am using just a single header.`

```
Or any methods through which I can avoid the page being reloaded when dialog is closed?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.load()` to load *popup.html* into a placeholder (i.e `<div id="PopupPH">`). This placeholder can be placed either inside `data-role="page` or outside it, depending on jQuery Mobile version you are using.

Moreover, in *popup.html*, you need to change `data-role=page"` to `data-role="popup` in order to treat it as a *popup* not a *page*.

### jQuery Mobile 1.4

Insert placeholder inside `body` tag or `data-role="page"` and load *popup.html*.

```
<body>
  <div data-role="page">
  </div>
  <div id="PopupPH">
    <!-- placeholder for popup -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Or

```
<body>
  <div data-role="page">
    <div id="PopupPH">
      <!-- placeholder for popup -->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Load *popup.html* into placeholder

```
$("#PopupPH").load("popup.html");
```

Inside *popup.html* popup div, add JS to create, open and remove popup once it's closed.

```
<div data-role="popup">
  <!-- contents -->
  <script>
    $("[data-role=popup]").enhanceWithin().popup({
        afterclose: function () {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    }).popup("open");
  </script>
</div>
```

### jQuery Mobile 1.3 and below

Do the same as above, except for popup placeholder should be inside `data-role="page"`, because jQM 1.3 doesn't support *external* popup. Also, replace `.enhanceWithin()` with `.trigger("create")`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! IN 3 months I will be like you!

Comment: @user3283104 better than me ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using the frames & popups in jQuery mobile, you can simply include an iframe inside, although dialogs are still probably your better bet. (Especially as a click outside the popup.. kills it)

```
<div class="hidden">
     <div data-role="popup" id="externalpage">
         <iframe src="http://www.bbc.com" 
                 width="480" 
                 height="320" 
                 seamless>
          </iframe>
     </div>
</div>    

<a href='#externalpage' 
   data-rel="popup"  
   data-role="button">COME HERE</a>

<script>
$(document).on("pageinit", function() {    
    $( "#externalpage" ).on({
        popupbeforeposition: function( event, ui ) {  
            console.log( event.target );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/tcS8B/
jQuery Mobile Dialogs don't refresh the page I don't think, it simply masks it with a new background for focused attention.

Comment: No it is not doing that!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<a href="google.com" rel="external">Test</a>
```